# What tense should I use after "to ensure" clause?

Tags: grammar

- Debugged the codes to ensure the game **works** properly
- Debugged the codes to ensure the game **worked** properly

Which one is correct? What tense should I use? Thank you

Comment: Depends on context.

Comment: The tense would need to be consistent with, or at least in relation to, the previous sentences in a paragraph. Without this further context it's impossible to say, but you could [edit] it into the question for us.

Comment: The context is project description for a project I did a year ago. Thank you

Comment: In a resume, all accomplishments are past tense, even your current job. I'd use code instead of *codes*, and something more exciting than *properly*.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want the sentence to mean. Note: Your examples aren't complete sentences - I'll add a subject.

All the following are correct but they have different meanings:

John debugged the code to ensure the game works properly.
*e.g. John worked all day yesterday and debugged the code so that it works properly today.*

John will debug the code to ensure the game works properly.
*e.g. John will debug the code tomorrow to ensure the game works in time for next week's demonstration*

John debugged the code to ensure the game worked properly.

*e.g. In 1990, John debugged the code to ensure that it worked in time for the release date in January 1991.*

John has debugged the code to ensure the game will work properly.
*e.g. After working through the weekend, John has finally debugged the code to ensure it will work properly when the manager comes to see a demo tomorrow.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was wondering what tense I should use in the context of project description. (a project that I did a year ago)

Comment: In that case I assume that you debugged the code to ensure the game worked properly.